# Is there any way to make like iPhone progressbar in Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Hello all i am new in Apple Watch development and Is there any way to display progress bar in Apple Watch? I have one application in which there is progress bar which updated with user location. i implemented same thing in iPhone but now i want to implement same thing in Apple Watch. Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a progress bar in [WatchKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WatchKit_framework/index.html) at the moment.

#### Workaround

A fairly easy workaround would be to design a [WKInterfaceImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceImage) that looks like a progress bar along with the progressive images to fill in the bar. Then update the current image displayed to match the percentage that your user's location has progressed.

Comment: It will be a VERY small set of images with compression and everything else. Believe me, 100 images won't take up that much space. Any apps that have animation in them have 100's if not 1000's of images in their bundles to create those animations. Additionally, if you're really that concerned, you could create say 20 images and only show updates in 5% increments.

Answer (score 11):

The most simple way for a solid-color progress bar in watchOS 2+ requires 1 image:

1. Add a group where you want the progress bar. The group should have the size of the bar at 100%.
2. Add a WKInterfaceImage to the group with an image of solid color.
3. In your code, call `progressBarImage.setRelativeWidth(CGFloat(currentValue / maxValue), withAdjustment: 0)` whenever the current value changes.

If you want a vertical progress bar, there is afunction for that: `progressBarImage.setRelativeHeight(CGFloat(currentValue / maxValue), withAdjustment: 0)`.

You could also create the image dynamically on the phone. I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This solution was WAY easier that the accepted workaround, and still works in Swift 5 / watchOS 5. Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easier way.

You can do it using two groups. The process similar as Fizker's answer.

1. Add a group where you want the progress bar. The group should have
   the size of the bar at 100% and fixed height.
2. Add an other group to the previous group using the same fixed height.
3. Create an outlet for the second group. (eg: progressGroup)
4. In your code call `progressGroup.setRelativeWidth(CGFloat(currentValue / maxValue), withAdjustment: 0)`